# Number of pairs of pairs with difference between first elements less than or equal to minimum of the second elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization

Given an array of integer pairs `pair<int,int>`, it is required to find number of pairs of `pair<>` such that the absolute difference between the first elements of the pairs is less than or equal to the minimum of the second elements of the pairs.

Eg:

```
Pair 1: 2,5
Pair 2: 7,4
Since (7-2) <= min(5,4) it is a valid pair
```

PS: I was expecting a better time complexity than the naive `O(N*N)`.

Comment: I honestly can't see tweaks able to reduce the complexity at first sight, but I guess there must be some small tweaks based on ordering the pairs, but I don't see how the complexity can drop much.

Comment: so - you're expecting, as output, an array/vector of values that match your pairs - so in your example you'd get a `[1, 0]`?

Comment: No, he wants the number of elements. Correct output would be `1` according to the question. Thinking if I find something faster than quadratic. If I do, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Are the integers required to be nonnegative?

Comment: @Demosthenes the type is int - so I'd say that part is quite well defined too

Comment: If 5 <= 4 all answers are valid.  Wait, why are you claiming 5 <= 4?

Comment: Any `x,y` pair with a negative `y` can be eliminated form the solution set in O(n) time, so might as well assume `y >= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's sort our pairs by second values in non-increasing order. Then iterate through the pairs in this order. Assume that current pair has index `i`, and look at all pairs `(j, i)`, where `j < i`. We know that minimum of the second elements of these pairs is `pairs[i].second` (because of the non-increasing order). Then we need to find the number of indices `j` where

```
 |pairs[j].first - pairs[i].first| <= pairs[i].second
```

Let's reformulate: we need to find the number of first elements of pairs with indices `j < i` that are lying inside the interval:

```
[pairs[i].first - pairs[i].second, pairs[i].first + pairs[i].second]
```

This can be done, for example, with [augmented self-balancing BST](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/spring14/Lectures/10-augmentedTrees/augtrees.pdf) (we can keep and update the number of children in each vertex) in `O(log(n))`. 
Pseudocode:

```
res = 0
sort pairs by second value in non-increasing order
for i = 1 to n
    res += number of elements in BST on interval [pairs[i].first - pairs[i].second, pairs[i].first + pairs[i].second]
    add pairs[i].first to BST
```

Overall complexity will be `O(n*log(n))`.

If integer values in the pairs are `O(n)`, BST can be replaced, for example, with [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) or a [Segment tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/).

Comment: I have to concede this is a better (probably the optimal) solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you treat the pairs as two dimensional points  then you can illustrate the problem in a coordinate system.

Now you want to join each pair (point) with all pairs (points) that are in the region above the point with a width of the y coordinate of the point. Two examples are given in the image below. Constructing the region in this way ensures that:

1. the y coordinate of the point you consider is the minimum of all points above.
2. the difference of the x coordinates of the points is no larger than this y coordinate.

[image]

The question now becomes, how can we quickly find the points in the area.

For these kind of queries [R-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) are usually utilized. You can build an R-Tree in O(n log n). The querying complexity depends on the selectivity of your query and in this problem on the data distribution. If you are lucky it is O(log n) but it might also converge to O(n) for each point.

However, if I understand you correct, you are not interested in all the pairs, but only in the number of pairs. If this is the case, you can add a counter to the R-Tree pages storing the number of points that are stored in each page. Then you do not really have to verify all points which can bring you closer to O(log n) per points.

Comment: Very similar to what I worked out; but isn't there a cone doing to the x axis under the red point?  If the red point is (5,5), then (10, 5), (9,4), (8,3), (7,2), (6,1) and (5,0) are at one edge of the cone of matches

Comment: Indeed very similar. I thought of only matching upwards, this way you will avoid duplicates. If there was a point in the cone below the red dot, then it would have been joined with the red dot in its own "joining step", right?

Comment: True.  You'd have to take care about what to do with things 'on level' with you still.  I guess only counting things to your left would avoid the double counting there?  And you reduce the amount of accumulation work you have to do because no more diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

Your pairs are coordinates.  Treat them as positions.

For a given coordinate (x,y) the coordinates that match form a cone eminating from the x axis until it reaches height y.  Then it becomes a column of width 2y+1 centered on x going up to infinity.

So now you need a way to count the elements in such a region without doing any per-element work.

Imagine you had a map from (x,y) to # of points above and left of that point (call this the square accumulation map).  Then calculating the column part takes 2 lookups and a subtraction.  It should be possible to build such a map in O(n lg n) time or so.

Similar geometrical accumulation counts could be used to efficiently calculate counts of elements in triangular or cone regions.  For example, if we had a maps from k to # of elements with (x-y)>=k you can calculate the count of elements in a triangle in 1 lookup there, and 3 lookups into the square accumulation map, followed by 2 subtractions and 1 addition.

Have an opposite direction diagonal accumulation map and you can now calculate count of elements in a cone as specified above.

If lookups take lg(n) time, building these maps takes O(n lg n) time, then we can simply iterate over each point (n of them), calculate the number of nearby points (lg n work), sum it it up, divide by 2 (as we double-counted each one), and we have an O(n lg n) solution to your problem.